# ASP.NET reCAPTCHA in Internet Explorer SSL Warning Message

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, recaptcha

I have implemented the reCAPTCHA solution (latest version), into my ASP.NET web project. It works fine and dandy in my local environment, but on our SSL encrypted server I receive the warning message "Do you want to view only the webpage content that was delivered securely? This webpage contains content that will not be delivered using a secure HTTPS connection, which could compromise the security of the entire webpage." This only occurs in Internet Explorer.

I've found, on these forums and others to change the deprecated server to the new of googles (old: https://api-secure.recaptcha.net to new: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api), but I am not directly referencing the javascript files, just using the .net library.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From browsing [the control's source](http://code.google.com/p/recaptcha/source/browse/trunk/recaptcha-plugins/dotnet/library/RecaptchaControl.cs), the control has a property called `OverrideSecureMode` that, when set to `true`, always causes the control to render via HTTPS.

[The MVC Helper](http://code.google.com/p/recaptcha/source/browse/trunk/recaptcha-plugins/dotnet/library/RecaptchaControlMvc.cs), on the other hand, doesn't seem to allow setting that property. It seems to be using `Context.Request.IsSecureConnection` to determine which hostname to use; discovering why that value is wrong for you is another way to attack the problem.

Comment: Thanks Dan. I don't think I would have found the source if my life depended on it!

Comment: Any suggestion on how to actually set the value of OverrideSecureMode in MVC3?  When I try to do this in my MVC3 .cshtml page which hosts the recpatcha HtmlHelper: `ReCaptcha.OverrideSecureMode = true;` VS says the definition for OverrideSecureMode is missing.

Comment: @TimH again, look at the source: http://code.google.com/p/recaptcha/source/browse/trunk/recaptcha-plugins/dotnet/library/RecaptchaControlMvc.cs :)  Answer updated.

Comment: @Html.Raw(Html.GenerateCaptcha("captcha", "white").Replace("http","https"))

Comment: slightly modified solution by Novkovski
@Html.Raw(@Html.Recaptcha(theme: RecaptchaTheme.Clean).ToHtmlString().Replace("http", "https"))

mine is probably older version of recaptcha

Answer (score 4):

If the MVC Helper is using `Context.Request.IsSecureConnection` as Dan has pointed out above, and your application server is behind a load balancer that intercepts HTTPS and forwards as HTTP, then `OverrideSecureMode` will likely be `false` and rendering would take place insecurely.

If behind a load balancer, one of the ways to find the originating protocol would be to do something like this (provided you have access to the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header field).

```
bool isSecureConnection = String.Equals(
        filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-Proto"], 
        "https", 
        StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Comment: This is what i use for getting "enviroment specific url" from current request, as described from [post - Stay away from Request.Url](http://www.rajeeshcv.com/post/details/40/stay-away-from-request-url)